# video and audio codecs

Tags: codecs

I want to install video and audio codecs on Ubuntu
I heard it is done with this code:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

But it seems that the copyright law is not observed (**nope**) 
Please help me install the codecs legally
Thankful

Comment: What do you mean by _"the copyright law is not observed"_ ? It's not observed by whom? You're in open-source territory. Anything you find in the apt repositories is most likely going to be open-source. i.e. take what you want, just give the devs credit if you use it in your own projects... (There is obviously more to it, but that is the general feel.) Unless its MIT licensed... in that case, we don't even need credit. Btw, if it is released by ubuntu, it is legal. Where are you getting your info? Ubuntu do not use proprietary software unless the owners themselves offer it.

Comment: ^^ ...except in rare cases where it is more or less necessary, and even then only legally.

Comment: Install VLC, It comes with all necessary video codecs

Answer (score 4):

You are misunderstanding the situation regarding the `restricted` repository.

The following excerpt **from the official Ubuntu website** explains why it is called 'restricted'.

> Our commitment is to only promote free software – or software available under a free licence. However, we make exceptions for a small set of tools and drivers that make it possible to install Ubuntu and its free applications on everyday hardware. These proprietary drivers are kept in the restricted component. Please note that it may not be possible to provide complete support for this software because we are unable to fix the software ourselves - we can only forward problem reports to the actual authors. Some software from restricted will be installed on Ubuntu CDs but is clearly separated to ensure that it is easy to remove. We will only use non-open-source software when there is no other way to install Ubuntu. The Ubuntu team works with vendors to accelerate the open-sourcing of their software to ensure that as much software as possible is available under a free licence.

So when they say "*separated for legal reasons*", they are referring to reasons that are affected by legal issues, not that the software is illegal to download.

In other words, don't sweat it. Downloading from the `restricted` repository is **completely legal.**

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories#Restricted)